# Intervalos para ejecutar System.Threading.Thread.Sleep

Tags: vb.net

Visual basic me esta volviendo loco. Estoy intentando controlar una aplicación ya abierta enviando pulsaciones de teclas. El código es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim seqc As Process
    seqc = New Process()
    seqc = Process.Start("C:\seqc\seqc.exe")


    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) ' Wait 1 sec and hit enter on main screen
    AppActivate(seqc.Id)
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) ' wait 1 sec, hit tab and hit enter in second screen
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
End Sub
```

El problema es que la mayoría de veces no funciona. Incrementar el tiempo de espera, tampoco ayuda.

Parece que **System.Threading.Thread.Sleep** no está funcionando correctamente.

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés. Sugiero sea migrada al sitio Stack Overflow o traducida al español.

Comment: Ya está traducido

Comment: Pepo: ¿Cuál es la respuesta de tu código? Creo que el método SendKeys no envía pulsación de teclas a otras aplicaciones sino que las ejecuta en tu mismo entorno (aplicación). Corrijanme si me equivoco.

Comment: @AgustinM. ¿A que te refieres con la respuesta del código? No hay errores ni warnings. A veces se ejecuta correctamente. Otras veces, la aplicación que tiene que recibir las teclas, se cierra.

Comment: Tal vez te resulte útil ver [Cómo: Iniciar una aplicación y enviarle pulsaciones de teclas (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms172702.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

daré una respuesta directa a tu pregunta, aunque comparto la idea de que deberías buscar una manera mas eficiente de hacerlo, y sin hacer aclaraciones técnicas, de porque no es buena idea usar Syste.Threading.Threar.Sleep, te dejo el código que probé con notepad.exe

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim seqc As Process
    seqc = New Process()
    seqc = Process.Start("C:\Windows\notepad.exe")


    espera(1000) ' Wait 1 sec and hit enter on main screen
    AppActivate(seqc.Id)
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")

    espera(1000) ' wait 1 sec, hit tab and hit enter in second screen
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
    SendKeys.Send(Keys.A)
End Sub

Function espera(ms As Long) As Boolean

    Dim cx As Long = 0
    Do While cx < ms

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        Application.DoEvents()
        cx = cx + 1
    Loop
    Return True
End Function
```